# Change menu color on mouseover and onmouseclick

Tags: html, menu, colors, background, onclick

My html code for menu items is given below

```
<div id="menuBar">
<ul>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/Main.jsp?menu=3&skin=1&p=Javascript-Menus">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/RootSipResourceUI.jsp?menu=3&skin=1&p=Horizontal-Menus">Add</a></li>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/EditAppId.jsp?menu=3&skin=1&p=Web-Menus" onclick="changeColor(this);">Edit</a></li>
<li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/EditAppId.jsp?menu=3&skin=1&p=Web-Menus">Remove</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I need to change the background color of menu items on mouseover and mouseclick events using javascript or css html. Please help me. I tried. But did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Refer this site. I think this is what you need.](http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/javascript-menu)

[code is here](http://www.menucool.com/horizontal/menu-code?menu=3&skin=2&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

Your links probably want the a `class` name of hrefLink, rather than sharing the same `id`.

Your CSS should have entries like:

```
#menuBar a { style... }
#menuBar a:hover { style... }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. I had tested it.I need to retain that color till other menu is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

All above answers are correct and they full fill your requirement. As far as onmouseclick is concern, if you wish to use Jquery, then....

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#menuBar > a").click(function() {
$(this).addClass("active");
});
});
</script>

<style>
.active { background:#3d3d3d; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have id attribute inside your link you need to style your links with css like

```
#hrefLink a { background-color:white; }
#hrefLink a:hover { background-color:black; }
```

Css id elements should appear on the page only once, so I would recomment using css class with example given above.

```
.hrefLink a { style... }
.hrefLink a:hover { style... }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had tested it.I need to retain that color till other menu is clicked.

Comment: Could you please show an example for .hrefLink a { style... }
.hrefLink a:hover { style... }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ClassA:hover
{
 background-color: #245250;
}
.ClassB:active
{
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```